# Uploading a file in a popup window

Tags: watin

I'm using **WatiN** automation tool. I've got a scenario where I need to click on a button, which opens a pup-up from which I need to upload a file. I tried using `Fileupload` but it is not working, because the file selection window appears and closes immediately without uploading the file. Please suggest a solution. Below is the code I'm using:

```
ie.Button(Find.ByText("Upload_File")).ClickNoWait();
//now popup appears

IE popup = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("http://localhost/admin/Uploadfile.aspx"));
popup.Fileupload(Find.ById("upload1_File")).set("D:\vinay\watin.zip");
```

Comment: Vinay, you keep logging on with different accounts. You are really messing up the watin tag on stack overflow. Can you log in as your other accounts and accept some answers, or delete your questions please.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the field (that hold the path) without showing the pop-up, or clicking any buttons? All you need is get the text field Id & do something like:

```
ie.TextField("Upload_File_Path_Field_ID")).Text = "D:\vinay\watin.zip";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue but using `FileUploadDialogHandler`

```
FileUploadDialogHandler fileupload = new FileUploadDialogHandler(filepath);
                            using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, fileupload))
                            {
                                browser.Frames[2].Div(Find.ById("draftTempMaterialFileDiv")).Span(Find.ByText("Document Attachment ")).ClickNoWait();
                                browser.FileUpload(Find.ByTitle("Choose File to Upload")).Set((@"E:\TEST_PROJECTS\3DLEX_New_Lib\TEST Template.docx"));
                            }
```

Though I have not yet figured out how to actually click on Open button, this code solved the issue of file selection window immediately closing